# Solve algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^4+5x^3+8x^2+7x+5=0$ how can we find exact real solutions? I tried to factorize but it is impossible in my opinion. It cuts real axis in two points.

Comment: Polynomials upto 4th degree have known techniques for solution.

Comment: Well, it has no *rational* roots, so it's not going to factorize easily. But since there are two real roots, it certainly factors into $(x - a) (x - b) (Ax^2 + Bx + C)$ for some $A, B, C$, where $a$ and $b$ are the two roots. Can you give us some context on why you want to solve this? Is solving it actually necessary for your goal, or would a good numerical approximation suffice?

Comment: ok original problem is $(x^4+5x^3+8x^2+7x+5)^4+(x^4+5x^3+8x^2+7x+3)^4=16$ Substitute $x^4+5x^3+8x^2+7x+3=u$ then we will get $u(u+2)(u^2+2u+8)=0$ Then this equation comes.

Comment: the given equation has two real solutions

Comment: It is junior Olympiad problem higher techniques need not here.

Comment: What olympiad is this exactly?

Comment: solution was not given but is was asked in 2007

Comment: Okay but is this IMO or some local olympiad?

Comment: Carrying on from $(x^4+5x^3+8x^2+7x+5)^4+(x^4+5x^3+8x^2+7x+3)^4=16$. If $u=x^4+5x^3+8x^2+7x+4$ then the original equation becomes $(u+1)^4+(u-1)^4=2^4$. Clearly $u=1$ is a solution.

Comment: @kingW3  no no it is not IMO it was asked in math youth magazine 2007.

Comment: @Arby ok I know I solved that case but $u=-1$ is also solution.

Comment: can it be that you have made a typo?

Comment: the Solutions are looking very ugly (in square roots)

Comment: Perhaps in the competition, they only expected the contestants to get the roots $-1$ and $-3$. With no solution given, we have no idea what they were looking for.

Comment: I know of one thing--$u$-substitution is probably not going to work!